# Subtract and divide dataframes with different length, but only show the ones with changed value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different row lengths, similar columns but not arranged accordingly. I would like to subtract df2 from df1 and then divide the result by df1 (to basically get a percentage at the end).

Df1

```
Index       Bircher  Club   Quiche
2019-1-18     16       1     4
2019-1-19     4        9     6
2019-1-28     8        1     6
2019-1-29     4        7     6
2019-1-20     8        1     6
```

Df2

```
Index       Bircher  Quiche  Club
2019-1-10     15       1     3
2019-1-18     4        1     1
2019-1-20     4        2     6
2019-1-26     2        1     5
2019-1-25     4        1     2
```

Outcome: Only the date 2019-1-18 and 2019-1-20 show up in both dataframes and can be used. Then Df3 is simply expressed with this math formula (Df1-DF2)/Df1

```
Index       Bircher  Club   Quiche
2019-1-18     75%     0%     75%
2019-1-20     50%    -100%    0%
```

Comment: Rename the columns in df1 and df2 to differentiate them. Like Bircher1, Bircher2, etc. Inner join the two dataframes on date. This will give you a single dataframe with only the common dates. Then just create new calculated columns with your desired formula. Something like `df['Bircher_pct'] = (df['Bircher1'] - df['Bircher2']) / df['Bircher1']` . Then just filter the df to just the 3 pct columns you want.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly rename the columns. See my answer below, it's simple and can work for any number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from the top of my head:

```
# Join the tables to find common rows
merged_df = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='Left', rsuffix='Right', how='inner')

# Calculate the required percentages, column by column
for col in df1.columns:
    merged_df[col] = (merged_df[col + 'Left'] - merged_df[col + 'Right']) / merged_df[col + 'Left']

# Optionally delete all other columns except df1.columns
merged_df = merged_df.loc[:, df1.columns.values]
```

This assumes that you want to compute the percentage for all columns.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This seems like a lot of work, considering that I have 10-20 columns. Is there not a simpler way?

Comment: Do you want to compute the percentage for all 10-20 columns? If so the above code will work as-is. What's your exact query?

Comment: I now understand what you mean. I tried your code but it somehow does not join the two dataframes properly, the columns are there but no rows. I am trying to find what is the issue as the index of the two dataframes have the same format.

Comment: I changed the "how="outer"" and they all appeared but python somehow does no recognize that 2019-1-18  from df1 and 2019-1-18 from df2 should be glued together...any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I had to convert df1 index to datetime as well as I had done with df2 and then it worked. Great. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Yes it is always better to work on the correct data types. Only during input/output are string representations okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use groupby and nth

```
x = pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(level=0)

fg = ((x.nth(0) - x.nth(-1) )/x.nth(0))*100

fg[fg!= 0].dropna()
```